# p-adic Fractional Differentiation

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, fractional-calculus

The other day I had a fun thought that we can have p-adic "fractional" derivatives by extending the usual integer order derivatives to p-adic orders in some special cases.

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \exp(kx) = k^n \exp(kx)$$

We can naively extend $n$ to a p-adic integer here, since $k^n$ is well defined for $|k-1|_p < 1$. Additionally, $e^{kx}$ converges for $|x|_p < p^\frac{-1}{p-1}$, so any linear combination of exponentials of this form will also have a well defined "fractional" derivative.

These are some very harsh restrictions, so my question is, is there a larger class of functions or orders of derivatives that we can have p-adic fractional derivatives? Furthermore as a side question, is there any reason to want to do any of this other than pure novelty?

Comment: It does look novel to me.

Comment: If I recall correctly, some kind of fractional derivatives of functions on $p$-adics is treated in Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus*, and my former colleague Enno Nagel has written several papers about this (http://ongel.de/). For those, however, one seems to extend $n$ to *real*, not $p$-adic numbers. Things might still match for rational $n$.

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting, and you raise an interesting question for if they're equivalent. Speaking of rationals, it seems rational exponents can also be looked at in the algebraic closure, but I don't see any kind of way to pick a canonical choice there, so I'm curious to what extent they line up.